# How to create one time project setup in Java

Tags: java, sqlite, installation

I searched a lot but couldn't find the appropriate answer. I have a working project in java which uses a database to store and retrieve. But, if I create an executable and port it to some other system, the I have to create all the tables manually. So, is there a way to run a one time setup in order to set all the required tables and and initial settings for the program. I am using SQLite.

Let me know the resources or best practices to achieve this functionality.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: create a server and on running your app if it doesnt find the db have ti contact the server and retrieve everything?

Comment: But then I will have to run that command every time when I start the application...

Comment: only if it doesnt find the db, yes.